# In Hive, how to combine multiple rows from joined table as single JSON array in first table?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have two tables as follows:

```
users table
==========================  
| user_id   name     age |  
|=========================  
|  1        pete      20 |  
|  2        sam       21 |  
|  3        nash      22 |  
==========================

hobbies table
=========================
| user_id   hobby       |
|========================
|  1        football    |
|  1        running     |
|  1        basketball  |
=========================
```

I would like to make a single Hive query that can return rows in this format:

```
{ "user_id":1, "name":"pete", "hobbies":["football", "running", "basketball"] }
```

Comment: do you want the output as rows?

Comment: Yes, the output as rows but I'd like the connected table results as json array within the same row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables and use `collect_list` to get the hobbies per user into an `array`.

```
select u.user_id,u.name,collect_list(h.hobby) as hobbies
from users u
join hobbies h on u.user_id=h.user_id
group by u.user_id,u.name
```

Use `collect_set` to get unique values in case there are duplicates.

Comment: thank you for helping.  I have another related question that I have posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56088344/6444286  Would you know how to solve that?